# Dash Lights and Headlight Angle Adjust Stop Working

Tags: electrical, nissan, lights, almera

I have a 99 Nissan Almera on which the horn was replaced a few days ago and I just noticed that the dashboard lights and the headlight angle adjuster are no long working.  A more powerful aftermarket horn which required extra wiring and fuses had previously been installed, and the extra wiring / fuses were removed ( as much as I can tell ).  I'm pretty certain this is the first time I've driven at night since the repair, and I'm 100% certain it was working before the repair.

**EDIT**

I've found that the 10A fuse labeled "tail" was blown, and after replacing it and turn on the lights it immediately blew again.  So obviously, the guy who did the horn wired something wrong and created a short in the system which is blowing the "tail" fuse.  The thing is he lives an hour drive away and did the horn as a favor to the seller, so I think I'll probably be stuck trying to figure this out myself... Any ideas how I should proceed?  Just trace the wires from that fuse and try to see where they go until I find the culprit?

[image]

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like they removed *too much wiring* when they did the horn repair. I wouldn't even begin to tell you if my assumption is right, though. Personally, I'd take it back to the shop and tell them to fix it, because it was working prior to and the wiring for a lot of that goes in the same general area as the horn does. Also, check your fuses. They may have robbed a fuse from one slot to provide it for the horn.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yeah, after writing the question I had the same thought, maybe they took a fuse out and forgot to put it back... That's the first thing I'll check when I get a chance.

Comment: @Paulster2 I found a burnt fuse changed it and it burnt out again any idea how to track down the short?

Comment: @Paulster2 I found the problem and it was a short in the extra wiring and relay that they put in for the extra horn.  I removed the fuse from the extra horn relay, disconnected it from the battery and put relectrical tape on the wires.  I should probably just completely remove the relay.

Comment: Good deal. 9 out of 10 times, bad things happen when others screw with what the manufacturer had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and it was a short in the extra wiring and relay that they put in for the extra horn. Apparently, when they removed the broken extra horn and replaced it with a standard horn, they created a short somehow. I removed the fuse from the extra horn relay, disconnected it from the battery and put electrical tape on the wires. That solved the problem.